# I am looking for an expression, idiom or proverb for a Hindi saying "ulta karobar" which literally means "turtled business" or "upside-down acts"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

I am looking for an expression, idiom or proverb for a Hindi saying "ulta karobar" which literally means "turtled business" or "upside-down business" and relates to the disorderly handling of an issue or passing of foolish twisted laws that cause inconvenience or commotion/annoyance for the population.

After reflecting over such above mentioned doings, one can say with a sigh, "This is "ulta karobar."

What is the equivalent expression in English?

Comment: This is a *real mess*!!!

Answer (score 1):

**fubar** -- This is **fubar**.

(An acronym originating in the military for such bureaucratic impedance to efficiency.)

It's similar to snafu, but more emphatic.

Answer (score 1):

One popular and similarly themed English idiom is ***[putting the cart before the horse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20the%20cart%20before%20the%20horse)***:

> to do things in the wrong order
>   • *People are putting the cart before the horse by making plans on how to spend the money before we are even certain that the money will be available.*
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20the%20cart%20before%20the%20horse)*</sub>